# PostgreSQL — Select column1 where MIN(column2)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-13

**NOTE: I WANT TO AVOID DISTINCT ON FOR PERFORMANCE REASONS.**

**NOTE 2: I WAS WRONG. USING PROPER INDEXES THE QUERY WORKED AWESOME THANKS TO @Gordon Linoff!**

Having the following structure:

```
| id | image_url     | sort | t1_id |
|----|---------------|------|-------|
| 1  | https://.../1 | 10   | 1     |
| 2  | https://.../2 | 20   | 1     |
| 3  | https://.../3 | 30   | 1     |
| 4  | https://.../4 | 30   | 2     |
| 5  | https://.../5 | 20   | 2     |
| 6  | https://.../6 | 10   | 2     |
```

I want to fetch **the lowest `sort` row's `image_url` column by `t1_id`**, similar to the following:

```sql
SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE MIN(sort) GROUP BY (t1_id);
```

Getting the following result:

```
| id | image_url     | sort | t1_id |
|----|---------------|------|-------|
| 1  | https://.../1 | 10   | 1     |
| 6  | https://.../6 | 10   | 2     |
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am pretty sure that `DISTINCT ON` is not slower than any other technique to achieve the same (e.g. with `ROW_NUMBER` or a sbquery). So, your problem is more general and you may just want to provide your DBMS with an appropriate index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres has a handy extension called `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (t1_id) t2.*
from t2
order by t1_id, sort asc;
```

This is usually the fastest way to approach such a problem.  In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `(t1_id, sort [desc])`.

However, you can try another approach such as:

```
select t2.*
from t2
where t2.sort = (select min(tt2.sort)
                 from t2 tt2
                 where tt2.t1_id = t2.t1_id
                );
```

This would use the same index.  If this is faster, please post a comment with the relevant performance.

Comment: As I noted on the first line, the ms from my query goes from 200ms to 700ms with distinct on.

Comment: @Zeswen . . . The query has to do more work, so it is not surprising that it takes more time.  `distinct on` is often the fastest method -- particularly with the right index.

Comment: I did not notice the index you mentioned with `(t1_id, sort [asc])`. It really did the trick with performance, thank you very much! Learned something new with the `asc` in the index :)